# how can i solve npx create-react-app problem

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app

when I run `npx create-react-app` the process is blocked at this step (see image 1) and my react project is not created. I tried to clear the cache or use `npm i -g create-react-app` then `create-react-app` application but still get the same result.
[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIzlF.jpg)

Comment: it looks like your boiler plate is ready then why are you using this command again

Comment: Why you need to run this command `npx create-react-app` in this project. Seems project is already created. Just run `npm install` and then `npm start`

Comment: and that's the problem. everything seems perfectly fine, but the folder containing my project is not created